# Acoustic guitar pickups used in satellites: why?

Tags: acoustics, collision, satellites

Some years ago, a weather satellite manufacturer in the SFO bay area was buying small quantities of piezoelectric acoustic guitar pickups from one of the big music supply houses, which greatly puzzled their sales rep. What were they doing with pickups intended to be glued to the underside of an acoustic guitar bridge?

Answer (score 6):

The manufacturer was building those pickups into the despinning system bearing supports, and also affixing them to the inside of the satellite case.

The pickup glued to the case was intended to monitor micrometeorite impacts while in orbit. The acoustic signal from that pickup was beamed to earth on an unused downlink channel so you could listen for impacts whenever you wished.

Regarding the bearings in the despinner: many satellites are spin-stabilized during deployment. Once parked in the correct orbit, the satellite must then be *despun* so its high-gain antennas can point in the right direction instead of spinning around and around.

To do this, the (cylindrical) satellite is broken up into two halves. an electric motor is mounted between them with its rotor *shaft* connected to one end and the motor *casing* to the other. Turning on the electric motor causes the two halves to rotate in opposite directions, which speeds up one end while slowing down the other. the motor power is delicately adjusted so that the rotation speed of end of the satellite with the antennas on it is zero (while the other end is spinning fast). Tweaking the motor power allows the antennas to be steered around the roll axis to exactly the correct angle to hit the ground station with the telemetry beam.

The wear in those bearings causes them to rumble, and that is monitored with guitar pickups mounted in the bearing supports. the acoustic output of those pickups is sent to the ground station on another downlink channel.